# dynamically declare/create lists in python

Tags: python, list, dynamic, creation, variable-declaration

I am a beginner in python and met with a requirement to declare/create some lists dynamically for in python script. I need something like to create 4 list objects like depth_1,depth_2,depth_3,depth_4 on giving an input of 4.Like

```
for (i = 1; i <= depth; i++)
{
    ArrayList depth_i = new ArrayList();  //or as depth_i=[] in python
}
```

so that it should dynamically create lists.Can you please provide me a solution to this?

Thanking You in anticipation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do what you want using `globals()` or `locals()`.

```
>>> g = globals()
>>> for i in range(1, 5):
...     g['depth_{0}'.format(i)] = []
... 
>>> depth_1
[]
>>> depth_2
[]
>>> depth_3
[]
>>> depth_4
[]
>>> depth_5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'depth_5' is not defined
```

Why don't you use list of list?

```
>>> depths = [[] for i in range(4)]
>>> depths
[[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Thanks..But Iam getting an error while using the first method     g['depth_{}'.format(i)] = []
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @ChithraNair, I updated the code to run on Python 2.6.

Comment: while trying to print depths_1 its telling undefined variable! Yes I think I can go with using list of lists

Comment: @ChithraNair, I used `depth_..` instead of `depths_..` for variable names.

Comment: Thanks...yes, even i tried with depth_1, it was complaining in red mark of an undefined variable but running it gave the result!!!Thank u so much...By the way, is it a bad choice to use globals here?

Comment: red mark? You maybe using an IDE. Many IDEs does not handle variables created this way. As other answered, making variables this way (using globals) is not good way to go.

Comment: Actually i made use of the second method. I appended another list to say depths[1] using depths[1].append(list), before calling this list and depths[1] had values, but after calling append, depth[1] becomes None! Am I doing something wrong?Request you to kindly give some guidelines

Comment: @ChithraNair, I can't understand what you comment. Please post another question with the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can not achieve this in Python. The way recommended is to use a list to store the four list you want:

```
>>> depth = [[]]*4
>>> depth
[[], [], [], []]
```

Or use tricks like `globals` and `locals`. But don't do that. This is not a good choice:

```
>>> for i in range(4):
...     globals()['depth_{}'.format(i)] = []
>>> depth_1
[]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting the error below while executing this g['depth_{}'.format(i)] = []
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Excuse me, why is it not a good choice to use globals() ?

Comment: It will register the variables in the global namespace. Sometimes it will lead to mess.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that `depth_i` is risky and so wouldn't use it. I'd recommend that you use the following approach instead:

```
depth = [[]]

for i in range(4):
    depth.append([])
```

Now you can just call `depth_1` by using `depth[1]` instead. If possible, you should start from `depth[0]`.

Then your code will be `depth = []` instead.